# Run contents of the buffer in vim

Tags: vim

I have found a comment in a Gemfile:

```
# ruby-debug19 is currently broken in the 1.9.3 release. You need to
# install it manually.
#
# To install, do this:
#     curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
#     curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75415/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem
#     gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem \
#       --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125/
#     rm linecache19-0.5.13.gem ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem
#
# When done, just:
#     bundle
#
```

I would now copy the file, edit the file, until it matches the given commands, `chmod +x` and then `! %`. Is there a vim way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have completely understood the question, but if you are trying to run those commands from within Vim, you can do so by selecting the lines you want to run (with `V`), and then type:

```
:w !bash
```

This will display as to take your selection into account:

```
:'<,'>w !bash
```

Hit enter and this will send your commands to be run in bash, and will display the output in a temporary buffer below.

You could also just select the lines the want to run and hit

```
!bash (no colon needed)
```

However that would try to write the output from bash into your current buffer, which you probably don't want in this case.

This is assuming you have bash installed on your system of course.

See

```
:help :w_c
```

in Vim for more info.